# remove facebook application from page via php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using **PHP SDK**. H can application owner can remove a specific user who has installed the facebook page tab application in their page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the "Deleting" section of [Permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions#delete).

If a user wishes to delete the app you just have to make the API call-

```
\DELETE /me/permissions
```

If you (as an owner) wants to remove the app, you can use the **App access token** with the call-

```
\DELETE /{user-id}/permissions?access_token={APP-ACCESS-TOKEN}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering... the actual request was for "how to do this with the PHP SDK". This answer, though I think it might be right, does not answer THAT QUESTION. Using the PHP SDK, I think you might want this:

Ok, so I worked it out. to make the "delete app" request USING THE PHP SDK, this seems to work:

```
$fbParams = [
                'app_id'                => <app id>,
                'app_secret'            => <app secret>,
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3'
            ];
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook( $fbParams );
$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp( <app id>, <secret> );


// Send the request to Graph
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $fbApp, <access token>, 'DELETE', <uid> . "/permissions" );
try 
{
    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $ex) 
{
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo("Error - graph returned an error: " . $ex->getMessage() );
    exit();
} 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $ex)
{
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo("Error - Facebook SDK returned an error: " . $ex->getMessage() );
    exit();
}
```

Comment: any reason not to use `$fb->delete('/me/permissions')`?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0#delete